# getting slower performance in textBox1_TextChanged in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, sql-server-ce

I have a search text-box in my app. In my database there are two column named English and Bangla. I can search either Bangla or English. there is a button beside search text-box.By default English search is activated. I can change the search option by clicking the button. It works correctly but problem is that the search is very slow. 
search option selection code by clicking button  is:

```csharp
private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (SearchMood % 2 != 0)
    {
        //search bangla column from the database
        button5.Content = "Eng";
    }
    else {
        //search english column from the database
        button5.Content = "Bng";
    }

    SearchMood++;
}
```

Code for searching is:

```csharp
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    List<dataLists> mylist = new List<dataLists>();

    string word = textBox1.Text;

    try
    {
        if (SearchMood % 2 == 0)// for english search
        {
            // show 5 words in listbox matched with entered text
            var contacts = (from m in db.Dics where m.English.StartsWith(word) select new { m.English, m.Bangla }).Take(5);

            string s1, s2;

            try
            {
                foreach (var a in contacts)
                {
                    s1 = a.English;
                    s2 = a.Bangla;

                    mylist.Add(new dataLists() { Eng = s1, Bng = s2 });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }

            listBox1.ItemsSource = mylist;
        }

        else // for bangla search
        {
            // show 5 words in listbox matched with entered text
            var contacts = (from m in db.Dics where m.Bangla.StartsWith(word) select new { m.English, m.Bangla }).Take(5);

            string s1, s2;

            try
            {
                foreach (var a in contacts)
                {
                    s1 = a.English;
                    s2 = a.Bangla;

                    mylist.Add(new dataLists() { Eng = s1, Bng = s2 });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }

            listBox1.ItemsSource = mylist;
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

How can I increase the performance of searching??? Can anyone give any solution|???

N:B: My table creation script looks like

```csharp
    public System.Data.Linq.Table<Dic> Dics
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Dic>();
        }
    }

    public System.Data.Linq.Table<Learn_table> Learn_tables
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Learn_table>();
        }
    }
}

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dic")]
public partial class Dic : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _Serial;

    private string _English;

    private string _Bangla;

    private System.Nullable<int> _Fav;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void OnSerialChanging(int value);
    partial void OnSerialChanged();
    partial void OnEnglishChanging(string value);
    partial void OnEnglishChanged();
    partial void OnBanglaChanging(string value);
    partial void OnBanglaChanged();
    partial void OnFavChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
    partial void OnFavChanged();
    #endregion

    public Dic()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="serial", Storage="_Serial", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int Serial
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Serial;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Serial != value))
            {
                this.OnSerialChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Serial = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Serial");
                this.OnSerialChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="english", Storage="_English", DbType="NVarChar(2000)")]
    public string English
    {
        get
        {
            return this._English;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._English != value))
            {
                this.OnEnglishChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._English = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("English");
                this.OnEnglishChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="bangla", Storage="_Bangla", DbType="NVarChar(2000)")]
    public string Bangla
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Bangla;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Bangla != value))
            {
                this.OnBanglaChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Bangla = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Bangla");
                this.OnBanglaChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="fav", Storage="_Fav", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> Fav
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Fav;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Fav != value))
            {
                this.OnFavChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Fav = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Fav");
                this.OnFavChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears in using `TextChanged` event Handler. Place a breakpoint there and you will see it firing twice and hence causing the slow performance for you. It seems a bug in WP7 `TextBox` control.

Use `KeyUp` event handler, instead of `textBox1_TextChanged`

```csharp
void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   //your code
}
```

Hope this solves your problem. !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use of AutoCompleteBox rather than use of TextBox. AutoCompleteBox available in Microsoft.Phone.Control.Toolkit.
Execute you select query at once when you select language on buttonClick and assign result of your query to AutoCompleteBox.Itemsource. It should really increase search performance.

```
 <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox  x:Name="AutoBoxFood"  Width="440" SelectionChanged="txtFodd_SelectionChanged"  FilterMode="StartsWith" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="70"/>
```

Comment: But i have to implement 2 button actions in each row of my list-box which i used to show my search result. @Jaihind

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes to the columns in the database file.

Comment: My table name was 'dic' and i found that itz index name was PK_dic. I quried in my code like  var contacts = (from m in db.Dics where m.English.StartsWith(word) select new { m.English, m.Bangla }).Take(5); Now what i need to do??  @ErikEJ

Comment: I have used a existing database. here is the full schema https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0dcpdpkoloq8gn/mydatabase.cs

Comment: When i query with "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES" then i found that my "dic" table's index_name is "PK_dic" . Have you got any solution?? @ErikEJ

Comment: You need to copy the file to the desktop and add indexes, or at least use my tools to create a CREATE TABLE statement, showing me code does not help.

Comment: I used your tools for using existing DB

Comment: I had a SqlCe database which i created in VS 2010 in another project. An then i used your tool ExportSqlCE.exe to use my previous database in WP app.

Comment: previously i gave you a link.on that file the generated code was there. dropbox.com/s/r0dcpdpkoloq8gn/mydatabase.cs

Comment: That is NOT a table creation script, that is C# code. Suggest you email me the database file...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43046/discussion-between-darkenshooter-and-erikej)

Comment: I am getting slower performance though i added INDEX in my db...Could you help me more?? @ErikEJ

Comment: Are you 100% sure the indexes are there?

Comment: yes tried by adding INDEX in there but getting no desired result